# Load Image and Videos into Recycler View

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-videoview

Does someone know of a library or methodology I can adopt to have a recycler view that shows videos and images like Facebook and Instagram?

I want the videos to play as it comes into focus and stops playing when not in viewer focus. Not pressing play for playing videos or pressing stop for stopping videos. It should happen automatically.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `Does someone know of a library ` asking for a library here is off-topic and will get your question closed, unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to this blog below for playing videos in recyclerview. And as for showing images you can add that check easily by checking the file type.

[play videos in recyclerview](https://codingwithmitch.com/blog/playing-video-recyclerview-exoplayer-android/)